# Intellij and cocoa pods error Installing flutter on my macOS

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am trying to install flutter on my macOS Catalina for overs 3 days this 2 error refuse to allow me.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✗] Cannot determine if IntelliJ is installed
✗ Directory listing failed

!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
! CocoaPods 1.5.2 out of date (1.10.0 is recommended).
please help me with the solution of this issue

Answer (score 0):

1. reinstall IntelliJ if you have it.
2. you have to update cocoapods below is command
   brew upgrade cocoapods

Comment: 1. i reinstall IntellJ but still have the same issue asking for Intellj Directotry.                                       2. for the cocoapads update is saying. error file permission to update